# What's up with BarChart?

Tags: charts

Mathematica version 13.2.1.0

macOS version Ventura 13.2.1

I began having odd behavior with `BarChart`.  I restarted Mathematica.

The attached image demonstrates the problem.  In the Wolfram Documentation window on the left, you can see `BarChart`s as one would expect.

Copy and pasting the code into a new Notebook `BarChart` shows up in red.
On execution it doesn't produce the same chart as in the documentation window.

More curiously, if I execute either of the examples within the documentation window everything works fine.

Solution and/or explanation appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I have the same M version, but with Windows 10 I can't reproduce your problem.  The red color of `BarChart` in your problematic result may indicate that Mathematica is having trouble with that command, but I can't say why.  Maybe you could post actual code used rather that a screenshot.

Comment: @BillWatts - I literally copied the code directly from the documentation window and pasted it into a new Notebook.  Both windows open at the same time.  The code in the documentation window runs properly (in the documentation window) the other doesn't.  The screen shot is the only way to demonstrate the problem.  Does Mathematica somehow run a different core for the documentation window?  This just seems odd.

Comment: Can you evaluate `Information[BarChart]` in the documentation notebook and your notebook?

Comment: I have macOS Ventura 13.2.1 and Mathematica version 13.2.1; the code works as expected. Presumably, some portion of your Mathematica file is corrupted. You may have to download it again.

Comment: @BobHanlon - That solved the problem.  Still no explanation other than maybe a cosmic ray flipped a bit.  In any case, your suggestion has me back at work.  Thanks.

Comment: @BobHanlon - The behavior I experienced yet perplexes me.  If something corrupted the kernel, why wouldn't it equally affect the execution of the same function in the documentation notebook?  Seems very interesting if somehow Wolfram has ring fenced the entire operation of the document window.  Does this suggest some undocumented capability or feature?

Comment: Had you re-evaluated the documentation notebook (or parts of it) or just looked at it?

Comment: Re-evaluated it multiple times.  Hence my perplexity.